# AVR-GCC Flashing executable does nothing, flashing the object file directly works

Tags: c, microcontroller, avr-gcc

I have an issue I don't understand.

So, I have a main file (main.c) that simply blinks a couple of leds.

Doing the following turns on the leds of the microcontroller:

```
$ avr-gcc  -mmcu=atmega128rfa1    -Wall -Wextra    -DBOARD_MEGA128RFA1 -DCPU_ATMEGA128RFA1 -o main.o -c main.c

$ sudo avrdude -v -F -c jtag3isp -p atmega128rfa1  -B 1 -U flash:w:main.o:r
```

However, doing the above, but combining the .o file in an executable and flashing that, results in no leds that are on.
The steps I do to make and flash the executable are:

```
$ avr-gcc -o uJ main.o  
$ sudo avrdude -v -F -c jtag3isp -p atmega128rfa1        -B 1 -U flash:w:uJ:r
```

I don't understand why this is so. Any help you could provide?

Edit:
This is for an atmega128rfa1, flashing from Ubuntu with gcc version 4.8.2 (GCC).

Comment: Have you tried `avr-gcc -mmcu=atmega128rfa1 -o uJ main.o`?

Answer (score 1):

Aha! I've found the issue.

After looking at related files and on avrfreaks, this link explains the problem: [link](http://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/solved-error-address-0x810010-out-range)

The solution is simply adding the following line before uploading:

```
avr-objcopy --change-section-lma .eeprom=0 -O binary uJ uJ
```